# Does void* reserve inheritance information?

Tags: c++, c++14, void-pointers, static-cast

Is it possible that `void*` keep type-information?
I tried to make it forget the real types (`B*`) by  cast `B* b` to `void* v`, but it seems to know its origin.
It is good-luck for me, but I don't know why.

Here is a simplified code ([full demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/544af3171b2683a1)) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class B{public: int ib=1;};
class C:public B{public: int ic=2;};

int main() {
    B* b=new C();
    void* v=b;                     //<- now you forget it!
    C* c=static_cast<C*>(v);    
    std::cout<<c->ib<<" "<<c->ic<<std::endl; //print 1 and 2 correct (it should not)
    return 0;
}
```

I expected `c` to point to the address of `B*` (a wrong address), but it seems to know that `v` is `B*` and correctly cast.

### Question

Why it work?  Does `void*` really remember the type?
How far can it "remember"?

### Background

I am trying to create an `void*` abstract class [here](http://ideone.com/fbUZGd), but surprised that it works.
I want to make sure that it is an expected standard behavior.

**Edit:** Sorry for the newbie question.
Now, I realize that I misunderstand about `void*`.

Comment: By using `static_cast`, you are *telling* it the type. If you instead told it some completely unrelated type, it might even **appear** to work. It's all just bytes underneath, being interpreted in different ways. (It would be [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) though).

Comment: The cast is only valid if `v` points to a `C`, which it happens to do. `b`, `v` and `c` happen to all point at the same address. When you use multiple inheritance that will not always be the case and the cast will produce invalid pointers.

Comment: @BoBTFish  But I have already trolled it by stating that it is "C*", not "B*".

Comment: You create a `new C`, so at the other end of the pointer is a valid byte representation of a `C` object. Why are you then surprised that by saying "at the end of this pointer is a `C`" (ie `static_cast<C*>) that you get the expected values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Undefined behavior is *undefined*. That means you might, just *might*, get the "right answer" anyway.

In this particular case, it is entirely possible that your compiler's layout organizes `C` such that `C` and its base class `B` have the same address. Therefore, if you pretend one is a pointer to the other in an undefined way, you get correct behavior.

Today. What happens tomorrow is a matter of speculation.

This is not something you can rely on. It's just a "fortunate" happenstance.

---

> It's a pointer to C, then a pointer to B, then a pointer to void, then a pointer to C again. All perfectly legal conversions.

No, they're not.

It's a pointer to `C`, then a pointer to `B`. Then it becomes a `void*`. But the standard is quite clear: if you convert a pointer to a `void*`, the *only legal conversion* is one that converts it to a pointer to *the exact type* that was cast from. So if you convert from `B*` to `void*`, the only legal conversion is back to `B*`.

Not to a type derived from `B`.

C++17 makes "the exact type" into "a pointer interconvertible type". But base and derived classes are *not* pointer-interconvertible, so it's still UB.

Comment: Got it. Yes, you would strictly need to go via  `B*` on the way back up.

Comment: @NicolBolas: can you add the relevant standard paragraph?

Comment: Can you modify my code in the way that can break it?  I have randomly tried to add more fields to both classes, but it still works.

Comment: @javaLover have `C` inherit from a non-empty class before `B`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: It's a combination of things. [expr.static.cast]/13 explains the behavior of `static_cast`, and for casting to the wrong type, it simply says that the pointer value is unchanged; it *specifically* does not say that it is a pointer to an object of type `C`. The undefined behavior of accessing an object of type `B` through a pointer of type `C` is handled through [basic.lval]/8.

Comment: @Quentin  Thank! It doesn't work anymore. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39932fa6104e4783

Comment: What OP did is the literal equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

*(Nicol is correct; my answer is more entry-level and doesn't go into language-lawyering; still, you should find it sufficiently matches your observations in reality.)*

---

> I expected c to point to the address of B*

It does.

> (a wrong address)

No, it's the right address.

> but it seems to know that v is B* and correctly cast.

It knows that every `C` has a `B` base. Because that is how `C` is defined.

So a `C*` points to a region of memory with some `B` stuff followed by some `C` stuff.

Your `void*` has remembered nothing; all of this "intelligence" lies in the definitions of `B` and `C`.